# AVAudioPlayer only initializes with some files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I'm having trouble playing some `files` with `AVAudioPlayer`. When I try to play a certain m4a, it works fine. It also works with an mp3 that I try. However it fails on one particular `mp3` every time (15 Step, by Radiohead), regardless of the order in which I try to play them. The audio just does not `play`, though the view loading and everything that happens concurrently happens correctly. The code is below. I get the "Player loaded." log output on the other two songs, but not on 15 Step. I know the `file path` is correct (I have it log outputted earlier in the app, and it is correct). Any ideas?

```
NSData *musicData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[song filename] ofType:nil]]];

NSLog([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[song filename] ofType:nil]);
if(musicData)
{
    NSLog(@"File found.");
}

self.songView.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:musicData error:nil];

if(self.songView.player) 
{
    NSLog(@"Player loaded.");
}

[self.songView.player play];
NSLog(@"You should be hearing something now.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for entering the party so late. Just want to post a tip so that It will be useful for any person referring this in the future.

A small correction to [shaggy frog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161161/shaggy-frog)'s answer. The correct usage would be:

```
NSError *anError = nil;
anAVAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:someURL] error:&anError];
if (!anAVAudioPlayer) {
    NSLog(@"localizedDescription : %@", [anError localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Had the same issue -  it was an intermittent issue, I switched form data to url and it worked too

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *musicData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[song filename] ofType:nil]]];
```

Here, is `musicData` `nil` for the problem case?

Also:

```
self.songView.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:musicData error:nil];
```

You shouldn't pass `nil` for methods that take an `NSError` object. Likely it will shed more light on your problem if you use it correctly:

```
NSError* error = nil;
self.songView.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:musicData error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error with initWithData: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with NSError... I'm new to objective-c and wasn't sure how to use it properly. I'll give that a shot.

Unfortunately, musicData is not nil in the problem case. I logged the URL that goes into it, and it is correct. I'll try some more stuff and repost if I continue to have an issue.

Thanks again!